# List View in Sharepoint WebPart Page

Tags: web-part, list, view

I have created a webpart page..now i want to add a list view(CustomerListView) to the page... so i went ahead and edited the page and added the particular list(customerList)..but the dropdown box in the sharepoint ribbon List Tab that changes its view(CustomerListView) does not drop down it seems to be locked to "Default"

Appreciate your Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Part in your page includes a single view of your list ("default"). If you want to change it, you need to edit the Web Part. You have two ways to do this:

- modify view in the ribbon
- edit Web Part (drop-down menu in the top right of your Web Part)